# Визуальный редактор ставит слэши. Как это исправить?

Tags: php

В админке сайта используется визуальный редактор CKEditor. На локальном компьютере работало всё нормально, а на хостинге стал перед двойными кавычками ставить обратные слешы. Из за этого стили не работают. Как можно исправить это? Чтобы слешы не ставились.

В базу заносится следующий код

```
<p> <span style=\"font-size:14px;\"><span style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><span style=\"\\&quot;font-size:12px;\\&quot;\"><span style=\"\\&quot;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;\\&quot;\"><span style=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\"><span style=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\"><em><strong>Pre-DatingTM</strong></em> is the world&#39;s largest Speed Dating service for single professionals with monthly events in over 70 cities in the US and Canada. If you are so successful and busy that you don&#39;t have time to meet new people, don&#39;t like to date clients or co-workers and are not interested in the bar scene then try Pre-Dating speed dating events! The FUN way to Speed Date!<br />
    <br />
    Pre-Dating is a fun, safe and efficient way for busy single professionals to meet in person. You&#39;ll meet other people in your age and interest group through a series of face-to-face six minute &quot;pre-dates&quot; in a private area at a local upscale restaurant/bar. Wow... many face-to-face &quot;dates&quot; in just 1 night!</span></span></span></span></span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз на локальном всё нормально, проверьте выключен ли параметр php на хостинге:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Если нет возможности работы с php.ini, то
проверить можно через функцию

```
phpinfo()
```

а флаг добавить в .htaccess

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

---

Всё это присуще php < 5.4